# Type level predicate based instances?

Tags: haskell, types

To create a type class that accepts the type-level naturals Z, (S Z), (S (S Z))... etc, you can simply declare the instances recursively as such:

```
data Z
data S a

class Type a

instance Type Z
instance Type (S a)
```

Is it possible to create a type class instance based on type level predicates? For example, I want to be able to say:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
class Type a b
instance Type x y when (x :+: y == 8)
```

Where `:+:` is type level addition, and `==` is type-level equality from `Data.Type.Equality`, so that instances are only created for pairs of nats that add up to 8.

Is notation similar to this available in Haskell? If not, how would something like this be accomplished?

Edit: This post was inspired [by the Haskell wiki article on smart constructors](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors#Compile-time_checking_:_the_type_system), where a type class `InBounds` was declared to statically verify that the phantom type argument passed to a smart constructor was in some range of `Nat`s, the smart constructor was:

```
resistor :: InBounds size => size -> Resistor size
resistor _ = Resistor
```

Trying to do something similar in my example (after using leftaroundabout's answer) gives me an error:

```
construct :: (Type a b) => a -> b -> MyType a b
construct _ _ = MyType

>>> Expected a type, but a has kind Nat…
```

The example from the Haskell wiki works because it doesn't use DataKinds, is it possible to pass a type of kind `Nat` to a value-level function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use not an equality predicate but an equality *constraint* (which is baked into the language, enable with `-XGADTs`).

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, DataKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, GADTs #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

class Type (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat)

instance (a + b) ~ 8 => Type a b
```

Mind that this isn't necessarily as useful as it might look – the equality constraint does not in some way *enumerate* all combinations that add up to 8, rather it allows all `Nat`-pairs to be instance, only demands a *proof* that they add up to 8. This proof you can use, but I doubt Haskell's still just *sort-of*-dependently typed nature makes this work really well.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this didn't work out exactly for what I was trying to do, so I've updated my question to include more context.

Comment: That example on the Wiki uses phantom types in a useless way: you don't need any argument to `resistor` at all, just make it `resistor :: InBounds size => Resistor size`, `resistor = Resistor`. If you do need to wrap a data-kinded value in an argument, use [`Tagged`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged) (which I'm not a big fan of, but sometimes it's just right).

Comment: Changing my code to `construct :: (Type a b) => MyType a b`
,`construct = MyType` still gives the same error though.

Comment: You didn't write the necessary kind signatures in `data MyType (a::Nat) (b::Nat) ...` – without them, GHC assumes `MyType :: * -> * -> *`, unless you set `-XPolyKinds` (which you probably should).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a type level function

```
type family NatEq (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) :: Bool
type instance NatEq 0 0 = True
...
```

And then

```
instance Type' (NatEq (a + b) 8) a b => Type a b
class Type' (x :: Bool) (a :: Nat) (b :: Nat) where ...
instance Type' True a b where ...
-- If you wanted a different behaviour otherwise:
-- instance Type' False a b where ...
```

You will need to enable a bunch of extensions, of course.

This works fine if `a` and `b` are constants, so that `a+b` can be reduced to `8` (or another constant). If they are not constants, don't expect GHC to prove the equation for you. That is (using `Int` instead of `Nat`), don't expect `Type x (8-x)` to be solved.